# How to allocate more memory for docker container?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have python flask app which loads to memory large file (3.5 GB). When I run that app in docker, it doesn't respond to requests, but container somehow works. When I try to run my app without loading that large file to memory it respons to requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default docker does not restrict memory usage by containers. However, on Mac and Windows installs, Docker runs in a VM and that VM is limited in how much memory it takes from your OS. You can adjust this setting in the Docker preferences for Mac and Windows.